# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create simple Java code which displays MSSQL server version:

```
public void testMSSQLVersion() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("\nTesting SQL query for MSSQL version\n");

        try
        {
            // Load the SQLServerDriver class, build the
            // connection string, and get a connection
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                + "database=master;"
                + "user=admin;"
                + "password=dss!Q;";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            System.out.println("Connected.");

            // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
            String SQL = "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY('edition')";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But when I run the code I get this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The "variant" data type is not supported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TypeInfo$Builder$16.apply(dtv.java:1996)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TypeInfo$Builder.build(dtv.java:2158)
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT ProductVersion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128)),
       ProductLevel = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS NVARCHAR(128)),
       Edition = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS NVARCHAR(128))
```

Comment: Is there any other SQL query which I can use? Also there are no column names?

Comment: `SELECT @@version` ?

Comment: Yes, but I want to split the result into columns

Comment: In this case use the `SERVERPROPERTY`

Comment: Some context on what info this SQL returns or how it answers the question would be nice

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is just to alter the datatype from your database side.

Go to the design of the table and change the column data types of the columns (productversion, productlevel & edition) to NVARCHAR(128).

I hope that this will work for you. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

I simply resolved by correcting the connector version of sql server  :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>9.2.1.jre8</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```